# Understanding the result of largeVis

Tags: time-series, clustering, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I am learning the `largeVis`, and trying some examples, but have some questions, any tutorials on `largeVis` will appreciate.

Problem:

1. `LargeVis` have faster speed than t-sne, but more parameters than t-sne too, how
   to choose an proper parameters for the `largeVis`?
2. There is an "NA" cluster in the plot, what happened?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(TSclust)
data(electricity)
attributes(electricity)$class <- "matrix"

library(largeVis)
set.seed(123)
ts_matrix_elec <- electricity %>% scale() %>% t()
visObject <- largeVis(ts_matrix_elec, n_trees = 50,
                  K = 10)
plot(t(visObject$coords))

clusters <- hdbscan(visObject, verbose = FALSE)
gplot(clusters, t(visObject$coords))
```

[image]

I suggest adding the `largeVis` tag because it's very fast and comparable with tsne.

Comment: Is their any reference to largeVis

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/elbamos/largeVis

Comment: Question 2 has nothing to do with largevis and is about dbscan. It really should be a separate question. The remaining question 1 is unrelated to the title of this post. I downvote until the post is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this algorithm but it is gaining popularity over tSNE.

Perplexity and K are the most important parameters in largevis.

NA cluster depicts noise points. Somehow largevis manages to find noise in most of the datasets. Only dataset which geve me no noise was Iris dataset.

Also we see some aspects of soft clustering with GLOSH values giving probability for each point belonging to a cluster.